# Can I use org.eclipse.core.variables... in defining attributes of other extensions

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating an RCP 3.7 editor by using `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point. What I need is to dynamically define icon path based on some conditions during editor startup.

(EDIT: The editor is actually just restored after startup, but it's not selected as active yet, so you can see only tab with title and icon)

I tried to work with `getImageDescriptor()` method in class implementing `IEditorInput`, which doesn't seem to be used. The only way that has some effect on the icon is changing the icon path in definition of editor extension.

Therefore I started to play with `org.eclipse.core.variables.valueVariables` and `org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables` for use in icon attribute (showing valueVariables just for easy example):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editor name="%Editor_TITLE"
            extensions="xml"
            icon="${FOO}"
            class="org.example.ExampleEditor"
            id="org.example.ExampleEditor">
    </editor>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.core.variables.valueVariables">
    <variable name="FOO"
              initialValue="images/obj16/editor.png">
    </variable>
</extension>
```

However, that doesn't work either. Is there some way to use dynamically defined variable values (based on current condition) that could change the path of icon? ...or I'll be greatfull even for a workaround suggestion, that will lead to successful changing of the icon during startup (like making the ImageDescriptor work no startup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables only work in places where they are explicitly support in the code. If the documentation for an extension point does not say they are supported then they won't work.

You get use the image descriptor from the editor input to set the editor title image by doing something like the following in your editor's `init` method:

```
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
 throws PartInitException
{
  ... other code

  ImageDescriptor desc = input.getImageDescriptor();

  Image image = desc.createImage();

  setTitleImage(image);

  ... other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer greg. The only problem is that my editor doesn't get initialised when it's not selected on restore after the restart (only editor title and icon from path in extension is visible in the tab).

Comment: Well Eclipse really does not expect an editor to be changing its image like this. I'm not sure if anything can be done about restore.

Comment: You're right.. It's hard to do this in such scenario. Finally, I have set a default sleeping icon on each editor and when it becomes active, it changes to the required icon with your code. So, you have actually answered the question in title correctly. Thanks :)